# C# multi-line lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I want to print a percentage value in one (or more) integer intervals. The code below describes `object.ProgressChanged` as an `EventHandler<EventArgs>` and `maxPercent` as a global `int` variable.

```
object.ProgressChanged += (sender, args) => (
    if (maxPercent < ((int) args.ProgressPercentage)) {
        maxPercent = (int) args.ProgressPercentage;
        Console.WriteLine(maxPercent + "%");
    }
)
```

I can easily solve this problem by doing this:

```
object.ProgressChanged += (sender, args) => aFunction(args);
```

where `aFunction` contains all the same code after the `=>` operator in the first piece of code.

I am looking for a more elegant way to approach this problem, if possible, in one line. Any tips?

Comment: If you insist on keeping Console.WriteLine, your hands are pretty much tied to what you have now.

Comment: "this problem"? what problem?

Comment: What don't you like about the second solution?

Comment: I was just wondering if there was a way to write this in one line. I guess it's not really a "problem," it's more just out of curiosity.

Comment: I'm unclear on what you want to achieve. Do you want to compress your 3 lines of logic into one? That will result in a mess, and it's pointless.

Comment: Can you please define "one line"? Frequently "one line" is used as equivalent of "single statement/single expression" irrespective how long it is... Also is method inside condition always returns `void` (like `Console.WriteLine`) - otherwise you can't easily use `?:` to create single statement...

Comment: Oh, is your problem how to write the first code snippet in a valid way?

Comment: @usr Yes that is what I wanted, I realize that I was not clear at all in my original post... Looks like Jeff Mercado already posted the answer I was looking for.

Comment: The duplicate this was closed against is a completely different question, by the way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
object.ProgressChanged += (sender, args) => {
    maxPercent = Math.Min(maxPercent, (int)args.ProgressPercentage);
};
```

As Jeff pointed out you should use `{ }` for a multi-line lambda.

Comment: In your case (without `WriteLine`) it is possible to write a one-liner `maxPercent = Math.Min(maxPercent, (int)args.ProgressPercentage);`

Comment: Ohhh nice one I didn't think of that! I'll update my answer